# links in code snippets

Tags: support, hyperlinks, stack-snippets

Could be a stupid question, but since I didn't found my way on this...

While answering, I would like to put links to relevant function calls to libraries directly in the code snippet. What markup syntax is suggested ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related: [Link will not work with code sample?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271966/link-will-not-work-with-code-sample)

In a code block or code snippet, you can't do this. The point of code formatting, besides visual appearance, is to make sure that code isn't accidentally parsed as Markdown. Otherwise it would be unclear to readers what the actual code is.

What you can do is add references at the bottom of your code block/snippet.

```
Bla bla bla

    code here

Bla bla bla

<sub>[`FooBar` documentation](http://www.example.com)</sub>
<sub>[`Baz` documentation](http://www.example.com)</sub>
```

> Bla bla bla
>
> ```
> code here
> ```
>
> Bla bla bla
>
> <sub>[`FooBar` documentation](http://www.example.com)</sub>
>   <sub>[`Baz` documentation](http://www.example.com)</sub>

For inline code, you can do this:

```
[see the `FooBar` documentation](http://www.example.com)
```

> [see the `FooBar` documentation](http://www.example.com)

or this:

```
you can do this with [`FooBar`](http://www.example.com)
```

> you can do this with [`FooBar`](http://www.example.com)

Comment: Thanks. Since I've seen some formatting accepted in code blocks, I tought it was possible. Sorry for the noise

Comment: Don't apologise for asking! :)